# How can I find all questions about a specific game?

Tags: support, diablo-3

Can we have a page, or question, that is available to anyone to add/edit all of the Diablo 3 questions already on the site? Something like a "sticky" maybe? If so, would that be something that would go on Meta or on the main site? If this is possible, can we limit the links to ONLY other questions on the site and not external links?

Comment: I note you're using forum terminology.  It's worth pointing out that Stack Exchange is a very different model than a forum, so you'll want to familiarize yourself with the native features to make the most of it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here, I made one just for you:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3?sort=active&pagesize=50

You're welcome :)

---

Joking aside, all Diablo III questions on the site are tagged [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3). If you want to see all the questions under a specific tag, you can just click that tag (either on a question or on [our tags page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags)) to see a page with a list of all questions tagged with it, which can be sorted by activity, votes, etc.

If you want to search a subset of the site limited to a tag, just add that tag name in square brackets in the search field, e.g. the query `[diablo-3] gem` will search all questions on the which which are both tagged [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) *and* contain the word "gem".

Comment: do note that if you're using more than one search term, and you want them *all* to be present, you must put a + sign in front of them, ie "[diablo-3] +gem +socket"